# How can I join a list of strings and remove duplicated letters (keep them chained)

Tags: python, string, list

## My list:

```
l = ["volcano", "noway", "lease", "sequence", "erupt"]
```

## Desired output:

```
'volcanowayleasequencerupt'
```

## I have tried:

using `itertools.groupby` but it seems like it doesn't work well when there is 2 repeated letters in row (i.e. `leasesequence` -> `sese` stays):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> "".join([i[0] for i in groupby("".join(l))])
'volcanonowayleasesequencerupt'
```

As you can see it got rid only for the last `'e'`, and this is not ideal because if a letter has double characters they will be shrunk to 1. i.e `'suddenly'` becomes `'sudenly'`.

I'm looking for the most Pythonic approach for this.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

My list does not have any duplicated items in it.

Comment: What do you expect for `l = ['split', 'it', 'lit']`, where the third word matches further back than the second?

Comment: @HeapOverflow I expect `'splitlit'` for this

Comment: So the rule is to crop each word just by its overlap with the word directly before it?

Comment: @HeapOverflow Yes, like this.

Comment: Does that can help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188296/finding-out-whether-there-exist-two-identical-substrings-one-next-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188296/finding-out-whether-there-exist-two-identical-substrings-one-next-to-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more readable version, in my opinion:

```
from functools import reduce


def max_overlap(s1, s2):

    return next(
        i
        for i in reversed(range(len(s2) + 1))
        if s1.endswith(s2[:i])
    )


def overlap(strs):

    return reduce(
        lambda s1, s2:
            s1 + s2[max_overlap(s1, s2):],
        strs, '',
    )


overlap(l)
#> 'volcanowayleasequencerupt'
```

However, it also considers "accumulated" characters from previous words that overlapped:

```
overlap(['split', 'it', 'lit'])
#> 'split'
```

Comment: FWIW, this uses `__add__`, which is slow, and requires up to `n` reallocations and copies for *each* item in the list. That's `O(n^2)`. Slightly faster is `__iadd__`. And `str.join` is faster than either of them on CPython due to the preallocation guaranteeing `O(n)` performance (among other things).

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Thanks for that insight. Indeed I was going for "most pythonic" rather than "most efficient", per OP's request: _"I'm looking for the most Pythonic approach for this."_

Answer (score 4):

Using a helper function that crops a word `t` by removing its longest prefix that's also a suffix of `s`:

```
def crop(s, t):
    for k in range(len(t), -1, -1):
        if s.endswith(t[:k]):
            return t[k:]
```

And then crop each word with its preceding word:

```
>>> l = ["volcano", "noway", "lease", "sequence", "erupt"]
>>> ''.join(crop(s, t) for s, t in zip([''] + l, l))
'volcanowayleasequencerupt'

>>> l = ['split', 'it', 'lit']
>>> ''.join(crop(s, t) for s, t in zip([''] + l, l))
'splitlit'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute-force deduplicator:

```
def dedup(a, b):
    for i in range(len(b), 0, -1):
        if a[-i:] == b[:i]:
            return a[:-i]
    return a
```

Then, simply zip through:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, islice
>>> xs = ["volcano", "noway", "lease", "sequence", "erupt"]
>>> xs = [dedup(*x) for x in zip(xs, chain(islice(xs, 1, None), [""]))]
>>> "".join(xs)
'volcanowayleasequencerupt'
```

Naturally, this works for any length of list `xs`.